# How to force gem that converts all bins to 93k multibins to output 93k native bins?

Tags: origen-sdk

My need is to get good old fashioned 93k native bad bins defined in my testflow. My ruby file compiles but looks like the gem is converting all bins to multibins. Is there a way to force this from my ruby file instead of hacking the gem files? If yes, going ahead with this, I couldn't find how to specify hardbin description and softbin description in origen. That is something I would like to add in the ruby code instead of on ATE.

Also on a side note, I am trying to force the output file name to something i want. Like in the sample code below i want the output file to be test.tf. The gem is adding some string and an underscore in front of "test". I don't need that either.

sample code:

```
Flow.create interface: 'MyTester::Interface', params: :room, unique_test_names: nil, flow_name: 
:test, file_name:  :test,  insertion: :prb do

  test_info1 = {"key_1" =>
          [{:testname => "t1",
            :sbin => 100,
            :patternname => "p1"}],
        "key_2" =>
          [{:testname => "t2",
            :sbin => 200,
            :patternname => "t3"}]
        }
  testnum = 100000
  test_info1.each do |key,val|
    puts key
    val.each do |info|
      tname, sb, pname = info.values_at(:testname, :sbin, :patternname)
      puts "#{tname} : #{sb} : #{pname}"
      test_suites.add("#{tname}", pattern:  "#{pname}", tim_spec_set: 1, timset: 1, lev_equ_set: 1, 
      lev_spec_set: 10, levset: 1, test_method:  test_methods.ac_tml.ac_test.functional_test)
      testnum = testnum+100
      test  :"#{tname}", bin: 10, softbin: "#{sb}", tnum:  testnum  

    end
  end        
  
end
```

Comment: I don't really know what a good old-fashioned native bin looks like. Could you update your question with examples of what you want to produce?

Comment: I would like this as the output!

run_and_branch(my_test)
       then
       {
       }
       else
       {
          stop_bin "1111", "Blah", , bad, noreprobe, red, 5, over_on;
       } 

instead of this I get   

run_and_branch(mytest)
          then
          {
          }
          else
          {
             multi_bin;

Comment: I see, thanks. Currently it looks like this can only be controlled on a global basis - either use inline bins everywhere, or use a limits table. There is no way to choose the binning style per test.
The global switch is `tester.create_limits_file = true/false`

Comment: Isn't this line "inline binning style"?                                                                             
test  :"#{tname}", bin: 10, softbin: "#{sb}", tnum:  testnum                                                     The above line is giving my multibin instead of a bad bin 10, with the softbin num i need.

Comment: I don't recognize that line, I think my previous comment still applies